# Java sort apps alphabetically but the system language starts first

Tags: android, sorting

**Thanks to adelphus's comment use `Collator.getInstance().compare()` solved the problem.**

I use the following codes to sort my apps alphabetically but it starts with English , how can i make it starts with the systems defualt language that similar to other launcher ?

```
//pm is the package manager
List<ResolveInfo> appsList = pm.queryIntentActivities(mainIntent, 0);
Collections.sort(appsList, new Comparator<ResolveInfo>()
            {
                @Override
                public int compare(ResolveInfo p1, ResolveInfo p2)
                {
                    return p1.loadLabel(pm).toString().compareToIgnoreCase(p2.loadLabel(pm).toString());
                }
            });
```

Comment: What is `appsList`? `List<ResolveInfo>`? You should use http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#toLowerCase(java.util.Locale) and specify a default locale to compare against.

Comment: Just edited the code

Comment: pm is packagemanager

Comment: You should not be using `String.compareToIgnoreCase()` for comparing locale-differing strings. Use `Collator.getInstance().compare()` instead.

Comment: It helps .Thank you so much .